# Permission Issue in SharePoint O365

Tags: sharepoint

I created a trial office 365 sharepoint account for learning. While creating my first Insert operation I got an exception as

> 

Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

My code is

In Load event

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext == null) return;
            Session["clientContext"] = clientContext;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
            clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);
            clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Email);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```

On button click save event(Name and EmailId)

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var clientContext = Session["clientContext"] as ClientContext)
            {
                if (clientContext == null) return;
                var oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SharePointTestList");
                var listCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                var itemToAdd = oList.AddItem(listCreationInformation);
                itemToAdd["EmailId"] = TextBox2.Text;  //My List
                itemToAdd["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;     //My List
                itemToAdd.Update();
                clientContext.Load(itemToAdd);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error Occured"+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It seems some permission issue. But I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked, that the user executing this command has contribute permissions on that list?

Comment: @Serv Its showing limited access permission.

Comment: There you have it. In order to write to a list, you need proper permissions. At least "contribute"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already faced the same problem while creating 1st time.I solved it by doing like this

1. Go to `AppManifest.xml` in your SharePointApp
2. Click `Permissions` Tab
3. Give `FullControl` Permissions to Scope `Web` and `List`

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed in the comments I have a strong suspicion, that you are lacking the proper permissions to write to your target list.

As you've said you have "limited access". This means:

> Can view specific lists, document libraries, list items, folders, or
>   documents when given permissions.

In order to write to a list, you need to grant the user at least "Contribute" permissions.

So this is not a programming related issue. Read up on the basic permission levels within SharePoint [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Permission-levels-and-permissions-49d456eb-d3c8-4402-86b1-deb911224afb).

Comment: My mistake.The account I created was  Microsoft Office 365 Developer  instead of Office 365 Business Premium Trial.Thats why the permission issue came.